# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'digest' (>= 0) in any repository - Why can't I install/find the Digest gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm currently doing Michael Hardtl's Rails Tutorial and in chapter 7 there is a section of code that begins with `require 'digest'`. I run `sudo gem install digest` and get this error that the digest gem cannot be found.

I've Googled around and there doesn't seem to be any leads as to what this gem changed to. Any ideas of how to proceed?

Comment: What's the Ruby version you are running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a gem but part of the ruby standard library

Comment: When I fire up the console and do `require 'digest'` it returns false for me though.

Comment: What version of ruby do you use?

Comment: My Ruby version is 1.9.3-p125

Comment: the return value of require is irrelevant. if the require fails it will raise an exception

Comment: That's true, false returning if the feature is already loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Depending the ruby version you are running, you don't need to make this require.

If you are running ruby 1.9.3~ for example.

You can try at console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3-p125 :001 > Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("test")
 => "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08" //result
1.9.3-p125 :002 >
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the Ruby version. In your examp,e you are using a Rails console which will require digest during load. A simple ruby (e.g. started with irb will not require digest by default.